# window.print prints different URL in IE and Chrome ?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

I have a web page which as a iframe in it .
This iframe as a print icon on click of print only the contents of the iframe are printed.
this is fine.

Now , while printing the URL that gets printed at the bottom of the page is the URL of the iframe in IE.

where as in Chrome the URL that gets printed is the parent page URL . 
I need the URL of the parent page to be printed on the page as in Chrome.

Any suggestions as to how i can control the printing of the URL in IE ?

Comment: It may very well be a browser bug, or just an implementation difference (I don't know how well printing is defined cross browser) Can you check other browsers? I think the behaviour in chrome is faulty. Also I don't think you can control the printed url.

Comment: Thank you for your reply .I checked in other browsers IE and FireFox print the iframe URL where as chrome and safari print the parent URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.print), `window.print()` is actually not part of any standards. Therefore, browsers can choose to print whatever they want, or place the contents wherever they want.